# PHP Error when searching in Low Search

Tags: low-search

When I submit my form, I get these errors in the error page.

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Warning 
Message: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array 
Filename: low_search/mod.low_search.php 
Line Number: 312 

A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Warning 
Message: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given 
Filename: low_search/mod.low_search.php 
Line Number: 331
```

Here is my search form

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="members" secure="no" search_mode="all" result_page="test/low-search-test-results"}
<fieldset>
<label>occupation_status:</label>
<select name="occupation_status" dir="ltr" id="occupation_status">
{exp:low_options:occupation_status}
{options}
<option value="{option:value}">{option:label}</option>
{/options}
{/exp:low_options:occupation_status}
</select>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

and this is my results form

```
{exp:low_search:results}
{if count == 1}<ol>{/if}
<li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
{if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
{if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

I am using Low Search 2.1.2 and ExpressionEngine 2.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled upon a little bug there.

Try adding at least 1 parameter to the Results tag. In your case, you will need the `query=""` parameter anyway to generate the results from the form submission. The `disable=""` parameter would actually be useful here as well.

I'll get it fixed in the next version.

Comment: Ok, I added the query="" parameter and I don't get the error. I also tried query="{segment_3}" and I don't get the error. It seems it only shows when you don't specify query parameter. But you are correct. I need to define query parameter anyway so this maybe a non-issue for me.

Comment: The error only occurs with EE 2.5.5 (as I just found out) and only if you have *no* parameters at all in the Results tag. So, it's a bit of an edge case, but shouldn't happen nonetheless.